# Would Google split a word if it has HTML tags on it?

Tags: seo, html, keywords

I need to highlight some letters in a word. I wonder if Google will consider the text as a whole word if the crawler finds HTML tags between the letters.

The text "example" will be written in the HTML page as:

```html
exam<b>p</b>le
```

so it is displayed:

> exam**p**le

Will Google consider "example" as a single word or will split it, so it wouldn't have relevance if someone searches for "example"?

Answer (score 1):

Usually Google only assigns special meaning to particular HTML tags such as `h1`, `title`, `a`, etc.

The `b` that you're using in your example used to be a significant HTML tag, but in recent years has fallen out of grace at the expense of CSS-based styling.

That leads us to HTML tags without any semantic meaning such as `div`, `p` and `span`. While I couldn't find any hard evidence to support this hypothesis, it would seem unlikely to me if Google would treat `exam<span style="font-weight:bold;">p</span>le` any different from `example`.

If you really want to be sure you can always set up an experiment where you add a unique nonsense word to a page that is separated by a HTML tag and see if the page starts ranking for that particular word.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right, using <span...> seems safer than using <b>, which in fact I think is deprecated. If I don't find any evidence I was thinking on an experiment, but would like to avoid it if not necessary.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion (using non-semantic elements), but some clarifications: [1], `<b>` hasn't fallen out of favour (or been deprecated), it just has a slightly different semantic meaning in HTML5 (see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element), and [2] `<p>` is not "without any semantic meaning"; semantic elements = elements with a meaning, which in this case is "paragraph".